# How do I input randomly generated integer values in a 2-d array in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

## I have written my code like this:

```
import random
a = []
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        a.append(random.randint(0,100))
x = np.shape(a)
print(a)
```

### This is my output:

```
[[], 79, 46, 29, 48, 88, 43, 57, 53, 70, 55, 89, 19, 49, 11, 79, 41, 76, 82, 90, 91, 21, 86, 67, 80, 93, 13, 38, 51, 27, 43, 50, 79, 87, 23, 27, 1, 64, 43, 81, 67, 48, 35, 9, 50, 48, 70, 73, 94, 58, 75, 60, 43, 73, 88, 51, 12, 74, 88, 72, 83, 100, 7, 10, 50, 13, 64, 74, 37, 76, 44, 37, 46, 42, 20, 20, 100, 81, 11, 83, 27, 76, 29, 15, 3, 18, 81, 5, 34, 85, 99, 88, 53, 75, 53, 12, 19, 62, 1, 51, 44]
```

#### It is a 10 x 10 array. The first value is an array and 99 rest of the values. Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import random
[[random.randint(0,100) for i in range(10)] for j in range(10)]
```